# Gradle: how to execute a task doFirst prior to executing dependsOn?

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

In gradle if `Task B dependsOn Task A` how can I add code to `Task B` which is always executed as first so as first part in the entire chain?

The following snippet is outputting

```
> Task :A
A doFirst
A doLast

> Task :B
B doFirst
B doLast
```

However the desired output is:

```
> Task :B
I AM going to set some variables/checks, pre A and pre B

> Task :A
A doFirst
A doLast

> Task :B
B doFirst
B doLast
```

> Is really the only method, introducing a Task C which is executed
>   prior to A (B dependsOn C, A.mustRunAfter C), so that it is first in the chain?

Gradle:

```
task A {
    doFirst {
        println("A doFirst")
    }
    doLast {
        println("A doLast")
    }
}

task B {
    dependsOn A
    /* doInitialize {
        println("I AM going to set some variables/checks, pre A and pre B")
    }*/
    doFirst {
        println("B doFirst")
    }
    doLast {
        println("B doLast")
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describe sounds like a bad idea to even try. Maybe if you explain what you try to achieve at a higher level, you might get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run you initialization logic during the configuration phase of the build. You just need to specify your task as follows:

```
task B {
    dependsOn A

    println("I AM going to set some variables/checks, pre A and pre B")

    doFirst {
        println("B doFirst")
    }
    doLast {
        println("B doLast")
    }
}
```

In that case, `println("I AM going to set some variables/checks, pre A and pre B")` is executed in the configuration phase, before the real task execution started.

You can read more about build lifecycle in the [official Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)